# C++ linking undefined reference

Tags: c++, linker, undefined-reference

I'm working on an open-source project: https://github.com/daniftodi/metal

I have ArrayHolder class defined in holders/ArrayHolder.h and implemented in holders/ArrayHolder.cpp

My code compiles; but in my main.cpp; I need to:

```
#include "holders/ArrayHolder.cpp"
```

If I don't do that; I get this error:

```
main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV11ArrayHolderI8FunctionE[_ZTV11ArrayHolderI8FunctionE]+0x10): undefined reference to `ArrayHolder<Function>::put(Function*)
```

I don't understand problem and can't find a solution. Please help me.

Comment: Include the header file in main.cpp and when linking, tell compiler to link your cpp file

Comment: Can you go a little more into detail what your problem is? Maybe some CMake code? Because "If I don't include ArrayHolder.cpp ... I get an linker error" seems pretty obvious. Just a guess: you are building a library and forgot to link it to `main` with the [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command?

Comment: Here is my CMakeList file: https://github.com/daniftodi/metal/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with templates; you need to define them in the **header** file; you cannot define them in the **source** files like you would do with normal methods or functions.

See this question for further reference: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Thanks. I found also a useful explanation here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp